# Asp.net GenericJsonWebHook behind load balancer

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-webhooks

I'm implementing the ASP.Net Webhook (GenericJsonWebhook) code and it does exactly what I want but requires an https connection. The server is in AWS and SSL termination happening at an AWS Load Balancer, with the "inside" connection being http. Anyone know how to override the https requirement other than downloading and altering the webhook source. (Yes, putting a certificate on the webserver is an answer but that's outside of scope at the moment)

thanks

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Found it - Add MS_WebHookDisableHttpsCheck with a value of true to the config file